# How to color names?

Tags: dota-2

How can I recolor my name in DotA2?

For example:
[image]

The radiant team has coloring in their names. Outside of the game their names appear like this: `<font color="#cc`... the rest of the name is cut off by DotA itself (too long to display).

I tried the following:

```
<font color="#0F">Wandang</font>
```

and

```
<font color="#0F">Wandang
```

both did not work

What am I missing?

Comment: Im ready to bet that you need to have created a team and your name is automatically colored (with the game color : radiant is blue teal etc.) when your nick is : TeamTag.Pseudo (or Anything.Pseudo) without space

Comment: a) we have a team. b) why would their names then change to `<font `etc on their profile page?

Comment: [6.81 patch](http://www.dota2.com/springcleaning/) : "All interface elements in League Matches now use Official Player Names instead of their Steam name". you can have a look [here](http://www.reddit.com/r/DotA2/comments/260ffy/colored_names/), [here](http://www.reddit.com/r/DotA2/comments/24dkmy/how_does_pr_have_players_with_colored_names/) or [here](http://www.reddit.com/r/DotA2/comments/278jrq/gray_tags_colored_names_is_that_a_known_team_only/) to get more confirmation. The hex editing is not supposed to work anymore

Answer (score 1):

Allright I did a bit of testing and it seems you can no longer have colored nicknames.

The colors come from an invisible ASCII char that sets it, so you can still 'chat' with colors.

For further reference:

[playdota](http://www.playdota.com/forums/blog.php?b=146964)

[dota2 color chat](http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=309638130&insideModal=1)

[dota spoofer](http://atzo.nl/dota2namespoofer/) (which should have worked before they disabled it).

Comment: That site seems to be a scam. The source code only contains advertisement and the site itself does not give any useful output.

Comment: @Wandang The site itself gave you a console command to run on the dota2 console. That workaround doesn't work anymore anyway.

Answer (score -2):

I don't really know if that this is possible in Dota but it seems its a quite simple HTML Part.
[Here is a Example how to color text in HTML](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_font_color.asp)

To do your name in green you should use

```
<font color="#00FF00">Wandang</font>
```

Comment: I thought the same but as you can see in my example it did not work.

Comment: you missing some hex digits. You setted only the Red part. It should be RRGGBB where RR the hex digit for red,GG for green and BB blue

Comment: There was an old way to do the name coloring: http://www.playdota.com/forums/blog.php?b=146964 thats why I took only 2 hexa characters. I will try your html coloring -> did not work.

Comment: @Wandang, I looked at the page you linked and seems like you have to use a Hex editor and not HTML.

Comment: @aytimothy that was an old way of doing it. Valve fixed that solution.